# Yii 2.0 restful routing 404 issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, rest, yii

I am trying to follow the Yii2.0 example as found here with my simple product table
instead of User.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html

I'm using the basic package, not advanced.

When I try to access localhost/product
I get a 404 error.

When I use localhost/index.php or localhost/index.php/gii
I get the expected result (the default homepage, and the gii tool).

Here is what I'm working with.

The config file web.php

```
$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');

$config = [
'id' => 'basic',
'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
'bootstrap' => ['log'],
'components' => [

    'request' => [
        // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required     by cookie validation
        'cookieValidationKey' => 'xxx',
        'parsers' => [
            'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
        ],
    ],
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'enableStrictParsing' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'product'],
        ],
    ],
    'cache' => [
        'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
    ],
    'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
    ],
    'errorHandler' => [
        'errorAction' => 'site/error',
    ],
    'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
        // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
        // for the mailer to send real emails.
        'useFileTransport' => true,
    ],
    'log' => [
        'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
        'targets' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/db.php'),
],
'params' => $params,
];

if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = 'yii\debug\Module';

    config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = 'yii\gii\Module';
}

return $config;
```

The Model Product.php

```
    namespace app\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "product".
 *
 * @property integer $ProductID
 * @property string $Name
 * @property double $Price
 * @property string $ShortDesc
 * @property string $LongDesc
 * @property string $PicUrl
 */
class Product extends ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'product';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['Price'], 'number'],
            [['ShortDesc', 'LongDesc', 'PicUrl'], 'string'],
            [['Name'], 'string', 'max' => 60]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function primaryKey()
    {
        return ['ProductID'];
    }


    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'ProductID' => 'Product ID',
            'Name' => 'Name',
            'Price' => 'Price',
            'ShortDesc' => 'Short Desc',
            'LongDesc' => 'Long Desc',
            'PicUrl' => 'Pic Url',
        ];
    }
}
```

The controller ProductController.php

```
use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class ProductController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\Product';
}
```

I have tried to turn off 'enableStrictParsing' and set $pluralize to false, with no luck.

I have also tried adding this .htaccess file which gave me a 500 rather than a 404.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

I'm sure I've done something silly here, but anyone willing to point that out will be a huge help.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible there is something in Apache that needs to be turned on that wasn't caught by requirements.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scallopboat - I had the same issue. I raised it on the Yii2 forum and got the answer. The url you should use is http://localhost/basic/web/index.php/products.

I was also advised to change 'showScriptName' to true. The advise was that otherwise the links won't generate ok.

It was also suggested I could write some rewrite rules to use a cleaner url.

Answer (score 2):

Just set `enableStrictParsing` to `false` in `urlManager` array.

Answer (score 1):

@scallopboat - I too have a similar problem. I got 404 response for `view` action.

Solved by following the instruction from,

[How to configure urlManager to use rest api with string id](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/59854-how-to-configure-urlmanager-to-use-rest-api-whith-string-id/)

```
'rules' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 
                'controller' => 'region',
                'pluralize'=>false,
                'tokens' => [ '{id}' => '<id:\\w+>' ]
            ],
        ],
```

Accessed the `view` action using the below url:

`http://localhost/icdp-service/region/[mongo-id]`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Scallopboat. You can try this way while you do not solve your problem yet.
  If you are using Apache as your web server,you should

- edit the Apache config file `httpd.conf` and find blocks like
  `<Directory>****</Directory>` and `<Directory "your web root
  dir">****</Directory>`,modify the `AllowOverride None` to
  `AllowOverride All`
- uncomment the `#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/ApacheModuleRewrite.dll`
- place the `.hataccess` file in your the base directory of your index.php